# Creating a route planner for a game map

Tags: dictionary, graph, leaflet

I would like to create an web based map of an fantasy map. The creation of the map itself is not the point, as there are enough programs that can create tiles for an online map. There are also enough frameworks for those tiles to be displayed properly (leaflet, google)

However, I want to create a map of my fantasy village that has an built-in route planner like Google Maps has;
You can click anywhere on the map, and ask for the shortest path between point A and B using the given roads.

What program/framework/technique would allow me to create such a map?

- An example would be adding a route planner on this GTA map: http://gta-5-map.com

Comment: What programs/frameworks/techniques have you found/tried so far?

Comment: @Andreas I searched for methods to make the map clickable. In leafletJS I made markers clickable, but this doesnt solve my problem. It should be something that a user places two markers, and some algorithm finds the nearest path and gives the shortest route available. I found no programs that enable me to recreate the routeplanner like Google Maps so far.

Comment: isn't this question highly dependent on whatever data structure you have available for your route network/"given roads"?Where is that data coming from.

Comment: @snkashis the road data can be on any format, as the original map is fictional. At this moment I have a table with all weighted edges between the points.

Comment: Can you post image of your fantasy map? If it has high enough contrast or if you have the right tools you might be able to scan it and automatically extract `ways` or `legs` of the `route` as a series of coordinates (like a geoJson `LineString`). Alternately you could trace it yourself and input the coordinates. Since it is a fantasy world you get to decide your own coordinate (grid) system. Leaflet can work for displaying this in a browser. I know this because may [favorite DayZ map](http://dayzdb.com/map/chernarusplus) uses Leaflet. Anyway: define routes first, then do routing.

Comment: This is a well-known problem in CS called the shortest path problem.  It can be solved easily with Dijkstra's algorithm.  Google that for plenty more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of software packages for route calculations on map data. I suggest you start by [browsing this list in the OpenStreetMap wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#Libraries.2Fdevelopment_tools) and researching some of the options listed there.

In case the integration with these tools is a big burden, read about the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), which is not that difficult to (re-)implement. Algorithms for "real world" map data tend to be [a bit more complicated](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Graph-representation).